# What does has in thinking_sphinx attributes do?

Tags: sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Can someone here elaborate on what actually does 'has' do in the attributes section of thinking_sphinx? I have gone through the documentation at [Thinking sphinx](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/indexing.html#attributes). But, couldn't get what actually it does.

Please help me in this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The source code](https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx/blob/master/lib/thinking_sphinx/index/builder.rb) has an explanation. Scroll to line 112.